# Is there a way to manually open doors if your Doors Subsystem is broken?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

If my door subsystem is broken, and in the middle of a large fire, is there any other way to open the doors to flush the fire or am I **DOOMED**?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When the door subsystem is damaged, you cannot open the doors yourself.  Crewmembers can open them by walking through them, although I doubt this is useful in a situation where you're trying to vent a room that is on fire.

Eventually, a fire will burn out the oxygen in a room and put itself out, although depending on the strength of your doors, this may be after it's lit nearby rooms on fire.

Personally, any time where I think I'm going to be in a situation where fire is an issue (ie, the "too near a sun" events) I'll preemptively vent as much of the ship as possible.  That way, if a fire does break out, it's more likely to burn out quickly.

Comment: The trouble being, if your door-control is destroyed, your doors are suddenly made of tissue paper again.  Fire will flow through them like pudding through an open hallway.

Comment: See, I've been caught by this. Blast hit my O2 and doors, and because my ship was half-vented, my crew couldn't access the room to fix it without being damaged. A non-vented ship, they'd have been able to trade off at the medibay, and had a longer "O2 buffer".

Comment: another reason why i love the engi ship.  having healing across all areas of the ship is just so useful in many many ways